# changing color for texts, I am getting color from backend, mostly I am getting color in text form , like 'green', 'yellow', framework is flutter

Tags: flutter, entity-framework, frontend, flutter-dependencies

Below is the function, I wrote for color change, now it works well if color is in hex form, but if they are in text form, instead of returning some default value, is there any way to use the text color I get from backend and use it.
One way to do it to convert the hardcode color in hexadecimal way and to use that changed color, but as I am getting it from backend, there's only so many colors I can do hardcode. Also there's no package available in flutter for the same. I have mentioned the code below

```dart
Color setBackgroundColor(String item) {
  var itemValue = item;
  for (var fieldItem in screenJson['fieldDetails']['fields']) {
    if (fieldItem['key'] == "issue_type") {
      var fieldDetails = fieldItem['option_values'];
      for (var option in fieldDetails) {
        if (option['value'] == itemValue) {
          //print('optioncolor ${option['color']}');
          return Color(int.parse(option['color'].replaceAll('#', '0xFF')));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return Colors.green;
}
```

Comment: How are you storing your colors in the backend?

Comment: @raw-chicken I am getting colors from json from backend like this color: {Application Approved: green, For Claim: blue, Review Stage: blue, Application Rejected: red}, the text is a key and value is color, I need to display the text in that color. And most the color that I get is in text form.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think you should be using too many colors, so you should have a limited color palate in the first place. If you really have to use the color from your backend, you can do something where you create an enum that takes in a string and returns the corresponding color. That would still be sort of "hardcoding", but would look cleaner.